# Getting username in ImageField upload_to path

Tags: django, django-forms, django-models

I would like to include the username in my upload_to directory path for when a user uploads an image. Here is what I currently have --

```
#model
class Avatar(models.Model):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%s' %(USERNAME) )
     user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)

#form
class ProfilePictureForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Avatar
        fields = ('avatar',)
```

How would I get the `USERNAME` in the model to be able to set the upload_to path?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`upload_to` can be a callable instead of a string, in which case it will be passed the current instance and the filename -- see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField). Something like this should work (`instance.user.user` because `instance.user` is the `UserProfile`, so `instance.user.user` is the `User`).

```
def upload_to(instance, filename):
    return 'images/%s/%s' % (instance.user.user.username, filename)
class Avatar(models.Model):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question. However, I would suggest the user the user id instead of a username. You never know when you would need to modify a username, which could bring some headaches of its own.

Comment: @JeromeParadis There is a problem using the id, as the docs say: "In most cases, this object will not have been saved to the database yet, so if it uses the default AutoField, it might not yet have a value for its primary key field." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

Comment: @Caumons Good point. In this case I assumed the UserProfile instance has already been saved and that the Avatar is created in another step. In any case, I think my initial point is a bit moot since wherever the image is saved, the path is stored in the ImageField object. The only problem is that you are losing some kind of integrity between the image path and the username if username changes are allowed.

Comment: I would suggest using os.path.join to create path

Comment: @IsmailBadawi - In my case there is not `UserProfile` form. I have some model as 

`class Document(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(DocumentCategory, verbose_name=_("Document Category"), blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(_("Softcopy"), upload_to=upload_to, max_length=10000, null=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Ismail Badawi answer is completely correct. Also you can use new string formatting and lambda function.

New string formatting:

```
def upload_to(instance, filename):
    return 'images/{username}/{filename}'.format(
        username=instance.user.user.username, filename=filename)


class Avatar(models.Model):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
```

New String formatting and lambda function:

```
 path = lambda instance, filename: 'images/{username}/{filename}'.format(
        username=instance.user.user.username, filename=filename)


class Avatar(models.Model):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=path)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
```